# CharSequnce variable.toString() returns empty

Tags: android, charsequence

I have a list item. Each item extends Textview to create my customized item.
In this class I override the `setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type)` method to do processing on text before I call `super.setText(Charsequence text, BufferType type)`.
But when I call `text.toString()` method it returns an empty string.

Do you have the same problem or have any tips?
Of course I use Unicode text - for example : `\u0661\u6662\u663`.
The list view doesn't have problems showing Unicode dates.

This is my override and process method:

```
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    process(text.toString());
    super.setText(text, type);
}



private void process(String guess) {
    StringBuffer correct = new StringBuffer(GameForm.getCorrectNumber());
    int s = guess.length(); 
    if (s!=correct.length())
        throw new InputMismatchException("Lenght of correct and guess number is different");
    acceptCount = 0;
    warningCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        if (guess.charAt(i) == correct.charAt(i)) {
            acceptCount++;
        } else if (correct.indexOf(guess.charAt(i) + "") != -1) {
            warningCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

`s` in `process(String text)` is empty!

Comment: please, provide your overriden method, most likely you process your text in that way that it becomes an empty String. Try debugging the app and see why does it change.

Comment: i update question. please see it.

Answer (score 1):

as I already told, use a **debugger** and put a breakpoint on `process(text.toString());` and see what the value of `text` is. toString() method returns the string representation of `CharSequence` so if it returns empty string it means that you are passing an empty string to your `setText()` method.

As String objects are immutable you set your view the same `text` that you pass to your `setText()`. **Once more -- high time to use a debugger**.